# Draw points and lines in legend text?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

Is there any possibility to get lines and points into a legend text in matplotlib?
I had something in mind like the following

```py
x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
ys=np.sin(x)
yc=np.cos(x)
pl.plot(x,ys,'--',label='sin')
pl.plot(x,yc,':',label='derivative of --')
pl.legend()
pl.show()
```

except that instead of the `--` there should be the same symbol with the corresponding color just as in front of the legend label `sin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading around in the matplotlib source code I finally found a solution that works perfect for me and that does not need any position tweaking etc. as it used matplotlibs internal V- and HPackers.

```py
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
ys=np.sin(x)
yc=np.cos(x)

pl.plot(x,ys,'--',label='sin')
pl.plot(x,yc,':',label='derivative of')
leg=pl.legend()

# let the hacking begin
legrows = leg.get_children()[0].get_children()[1]\
             .get_children()[0].get_children()
symbol  = legrows[0].get_children()[0]
childs  = legrows[1].get_children().append(symbol)

pl.show()
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a hack, but it accomplishes your goal and places all of the pieces (i.e. the legend and the text) on the plot in the appropriate order.

```
import pylab

pl.plot(x,ys,'--',label='sin', color='green')
pl.plot(x,yc,':',label='derivative of --',color='blue')
line1= pylab.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='None', linestyle='--',linewidth=2.0, color="green")
line2= pylab.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='None', linestyle=':',linewidth=2.0, color="blue")
leg = pl.legend((line1,line2),('sin','derivative of      '),numpoints=1, loc=1)
pylab.text(9.4, 0.73, '- -', color='green')
leg.set_zorder(2)
pl.show()
```

Instead of relying on the default colors for the lines, I set them such that they can be referenced specifically in the legend.  There are extra spaces left in the text for 'the derivative' for the second line in the legend, so we can place text (aka corresponding symbol/color of the `sin` line) on top of it.  Then you specify the symbol/color of the text and place it such that it lines up with the text in the legend.  Finally you specify the order, via `zorder`, to set the text on top.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution depends heavily on the used backend, it needs a fine tuning for the symbol position to be in the right place. Furthermore the spaces get's stripped e.g. in the TkAgg backend leaving no space for the symbol.
I hoped for a more general solution. Nevertheless it's a good approach, which I'll use as starting point for own experiments.

Comment: If the spaces are getting stripped, use LaTeX via `rc('text', usetex=True)` and `'$\text{sin}$','$\text{derivative of \,\,\,\,\,}$` to force the spaces for the symbol.